# Filtering Array of objects with array of strings to get result with '&&' clause

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

I have a data related to locations which comes from a different api and which needs to be used to filter another set of data based of locations selection.

```
let locationData= [
            {
            "Name": "Olympics",
            "Problem Type": "Access",
            "LS_ID": "421"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Olympics",
            "Problem Type": "Route Issue",
            "LS_ID": "420"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Olympics",
            "Problem Type": "Tools",
            "LS_ID": "420"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Olympics",
            "Problem Type": "Access",
            "LS_ID": "420"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Olympics",
            "Problem Type": "Tools",
            "LS_ID": "422"
        }       
    ]
```

The master data which needs to be filtered is

```
 let mainData=
 [
 {
  "SiteType": "Outdoor",
  "ID": "421", 
  "Name": "Olympics"     
},
 {

  "SiteType": "Indoor",
  "ID": "420", 
  "Name": "Olympics"     
},
 {

  "SiteType": "International",
  "ID": "422", 
  "Name": "Olympics"    
},
 {

  "SiteType": "Local",
  "ID": "423",  
  "Name": "Olympics"    
}
]
```

We have a multi-select field where we will be selecting **'Problem Type'** options (eg: **Access,Tools,No Entry,Route Issue** etc)

So on selection, we will we get array of strings like **['Access','Tools']**

The requirement is to show the SiteType which has both **('Access' AND 'Tools')** Problem Types, i.e; from above example

if the input is

```
  let selections=['Access','Tools']
```

Expected output is

```
{

  "SiteType": "Indoor",
  "ID": "420", 
  "Name": "Olympics"     
}
```

because LS_ID="420" has both problem types.

I have tried to iterate the selected values over **locationData** to get the **LS_ID on comparision** but, i am getting the all LS-ID's which  has selected values **('OR' condition)** instead of getting LS_ID's which had all selected Values**('AND' condition)**

```
export function filterWithIssueSelectedValue(mainData,selections,locationData){
  let siteIds=[], filteredSSData=[]
  locationData.map((row,index)=>{
    selections.map((issue)=>{
      if(_.includes(row["Problem Type"], issue)){
        siteIds.push(row.LS_ID)
     }
  })     
})

 siteIds=_.uniq(siteIds);
 if(siteIds && siteIds.length){
    mainData.map((row,index)=>{
        siteIds.map((id)=>{
                if(row.ID==id){
                    filteredSSData.push(row)
                }
        })
    })
}

filteredSSData=_.uniqBy(filteredSSData, 'ID')
return filteredSSData
}
```

Can someone help me in this filtering.Thanks in-Advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
let locationData= [
  {
    "Name": "Olympics",
    "Problem Type": "Access",
    "LS_ID": "421"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Olympics",
    "Problem Type": "Route Issue",
    "LS_ID": "420"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Olympics",
    "Problem Type": "Tools",
    "LS_ID": "420"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Olympics",
    "Problem Type": "Access",
    "LS_ID": "420"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Olympics",
    "Problem Type": "Tools",
    "LS_ID": "422"
  }
]

let mainData= [
  {
    "SiteType": "Outdoor",
    "ID": "421", 
    "Name": "Olympics"     
  },
  {
    "SiteType": "Indoor",
    "ID": "420", 
    "Name": "Olympics"     
  },
  {
    "SiteType": "International",
    "ID": "422", 
    "Name": "Olympics"    
  },
  {
    "SiteType": "Local",
    "ID": "423",  
    "Name": "Olympics"    
  }
]

const findSiteThatHasProblems = (problems = []) =>
  mainData.filter(location =>
    problems.every(problem => 
      !!locationData.find(locationInfo =>
        locationInfo.LS_ID === location.ID && locationInfo['Problem Type'] === problem
      )
    )
  )

console.log(findSiteThatHasProblems(['Tools', 'Access']))
```

Let me know if you'd like me to add an explanation for any of this code!

Comment: You could make use of `.every()` or `.some()`, rather than relying on using logical operators on objects and arrays.. If you don't see how `array.filter( !array.map(... !!array.find(...)))` does not need an explanation, idk what *would* merit explanation.. lol

Comment: Yes, there's some very concise syntax that might be confusing. What I meant was I'm not sure if OP would like me to explain anything in particular and I didn't want to write a really long explanation if OP wouldn't need it. `.every` is a good idea, I've edited that in.

Comment: I think changing to `.every()` cleared up a *lot* of the ambiguity. I thought it would need more, but it actually looks pretty straightforward now. Thanks for updating that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to filter first the id and take that result for filtering `mainData`.

```js
var locationData = [{ Name: "Olympics", "Problem Type": "Access", LS_ID: "421" }, { Name: "Olympics", "Problem Type": "Route Issue", LS_ID: "420" }, { Name: "Olympics", "Problem Type": "Tools", LS_ID: "420" }, { Name: "Olympics", "Problem Type": "Access", LS_ID: "420" }, { Name: "Olympics", "Problem Type": "Tools", LS_ID: "422" }],
    mainData = [{ SiteType: "Outdoor", ID: "421", Name: "Olympics" }, { SiteType: "Indoor", ID: "420", Name: "Olympics" }, { SiteType: "International", ID: "422", Name: "Olympics" }, { SiteType: "Local", ID: "423", Name: "Olympics" }],
    selections = ['Access', 'Tools'],
    ids = Array.from(
        locationData
            .filter(({ 'Problem Type': type }) => selections.includes(type))
            .reduce((m, { LS_ID }) => m.set(LS_ID, (m.get(LS_ID) || 0) + 1), new Map)
            .entries()
        )
        .filter(({ 1: count }) => count === selections.length)
        .map(({ 0: id }) => id),
    result = mainData.filter(({ ID }) => ids.includes(ID));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```